# Keras keeps predicting default values

Tags: keras, neural-network, multiple-columns, default-value

I have a dataset containing a different number of parameters in different rows. For example my dataset could look like this:

| Parameter 1 | Parameter 2 | Parameter 3 | Parameter 4 | Output 1 | Output 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | 1 | 11 | A | B |
| 18 | 42 | -999999 | -999999 | B | -999999 |
| 2 | 4 | 17 | -999999 | A | D |
| 99 | -999999 | -999999 | -999999 | A | -999999 |

-999999 is only a default value. Since keras needs the same number of input parameters, I decided to fill up the otherwise empty columns with this default value.
Unfortunately, this value appears very often, thereby leading to the net thinking that this must be some sort of important value (both in input and output) and always predicting it. The net can reach a 100 % accuracy easily but all the assumptions are false.

How do I tackle this problem? Is there any way to weaken the effect of default values in this net?

Keep in mind: I want to keep columns columns and rows rows (not switching). Values in one column (except for output) are always unique.

Comment: Have you tried converting all your inputs to one-hot encoding / `to_categorical` ? Try this instead of using default values, so have None/empty cells and use `to_categorical`. Then for your labels that are missing some values, try doing a multilabel approach i.e labels = [[A,B],[B],[A,D]] i.e. it lets you have different numbers of labels for each row.

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "i.e labels = [[A,B],[B],[A,D]]"?

I have basically two problems:

1) Every input array has a different length. That means, I have two options:
a) Find a way for keras to accept different length inputs
b) Fill up remaining empty columns to make every array equally long

2) Every output that shall be predicted has a different length. Sometimes, I need to predict two columns, sometimes five...

Comment: 1) Research one-hot encoding 2) If you can somehow identify in advance how many labels you need to predict, you can stack multiple models together, however this is most likely not possible, and therefore unfortunately you will need to research multilabel classification. You need to do more reading as this isn't a simple question to answer, but the above should help.